# Logging function is shell script not capturing all the lines

Tags: function, shell, logging

I have written a shell script to do logging and the logging function only captures the first 2 lines. It is not capturing the whole log. Could someone please validate the script and let me know what is going wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

#### Function to do the logging ####

dir=$(pwd)

log_file_name="sqoop.log"
log_time=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
write_to_log(){
   while read -r text
   do
     if [ ! -f "$dir/$log_file_name" ]; then
        touch "$dir/$log_file_name"
     else
        echo "$log_time" : "$text" | tee -a "$dir/$log_file_name";
      fi
   done
}

echo "Importing XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE table"

ssh $1 "sqoop import -D mapred.child.java.opts='\-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom' --connect '$2' --username $3 --password $4 --query \"select CONTRACT_ID,CONTRACT_NUMBER,CONTRACT_STS_CODE,CONTRACT_STATUS,SERVICE_LINE_ID,SERVICE_LINE_NAME,SERVICE_LINE_STS_CODE,SERVICE_LINE_STATUS,SERVICE_LINE_NUMBER,HDR_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID,HDR_CUST_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,HDR_PARTY_ID,HDR_CUSTOMER_NAME,LINE_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID,LINE_CUST_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,LINE_PARTY_ID,LINE_CUSTOMER_NAME,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_ID,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_NAME,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_STS,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_ID,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_NUMBER,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_STS,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_SITE_STS,BILL_TO_PARTY_ID,BILL_TO_PARTY_NUMBER,BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_NAME,BILL_TO_PARTY_STS,BILL_TO_PARTY_SITE_ID,BILL_TO_PARTY_SITE_STS,BILL_TO_LOCATION_ID,BILL_TO_COUNTRY,BILL_TO_STATE_PROV,BILL_TO_CITY,BILL_TO_POSTAL_CODE,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_ID,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_DESC,COVERAGE_BEGIN_DATE,COVERAGE_END_DATE,SERVICE_SALES_REP_USR_ID,SERVICE_SALES_REP_USR_NAME,SERVICE_LINE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,BILLTO_CSC_ID,BILLTO_CSC_NAME,BILLTO_GU_ID,BILLTO_GU_NAME,BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_SALES_CHANNEL,CURRENCY_CODE,CONTRACT_LIST_AMT,CONTRACT_NET_AMT,USD_CONTRACT_LIST_AMT,USD_CONTRACT_NET_AMT,ACCOUNT_TEAM,RENEWAL_SSR,RENEWAL_TEAM,SALES_REGION,ADVANCE_CONTRACT_FLAG,EARLIEST_END_DATE,SERVICE_LINE_TERMINATED_DATE,SVC_LINE_TERMINATION_REASON,CONTRACT_TERMINATED_DATE,USD_CONV_RATE,PRICE_TYPE,NET_VALUE,COTERM_DATE,MARKETING_PROGRAM,MASTER_AGREEMENT_END_DATE,DISCOUNT_PERCENT,PRORATE_FLAG,RGP_ID,CREATION_DATE,CREATED_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,LAST_UPDATED_BY,LAST_UPDATED_LOGIN,REQUEST_ID,PROGRAM_UPDATE_DATE,PROGRAM_APPLICATION_ID,PROGRAM_ID,ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY,ATTRIBUTE1,ATTRIBUTE2,ATTRIBUTE3,ATTRIBUTE4,ATTRIBUTE5,ATTRIBUTE6,ATTRIBUTE7,ATTRIBUTE8,ATTRIBUTE9,ATTRIBUTE10,ATTRIBUTE11,ATTRIBUTE12,ATTRIBUTE13,ATTRIBUTE14,ATTRIBUTE15,ATTRIBUTE16,ATTRIBUTE17,ATTRIBUTE18,ATTRIBUTE19,ATTRIBUTE20,ACCOUNT_SSR,SHELL_CONTRACT_FLAG,CONTRACT_START_DATE,CONTRACT_END_DATE from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE where \\\$CONDITIONS \" --split-by CONTRACT_NUMBER -m 4 --null-string '\\\\N' --null-non-string '\\\\N' --hive-delims-replacement '<EOL>' --boundary-query 'select (select min(CONTRACT_NUMBER) from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE) as minid ,(select max(CONTRACT_NUMBER) from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE) as maxid from dual' --target-dir $5/XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-table $6.XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE --map-column-hive CONTRACT_ID=BIGINT,SERVICE_LINE_ID=BIGINT,HDR_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID=BIGINT,HDR_PARTY_ID=BIGINT,LINE_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID=BIGINT,LINE_PARTY_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_PARTY_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_PARTY_SITE_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_LOCATION_ID=BIGINT,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_ID=BIGINT,COVERAGE_BEGIN_DATE=TIMESTAMP,COVERAGE_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP,SERVICE_LINE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=BIGINT,BILLTO_CSC_ID=BIGINT,BILLTO_GU_ID=BIGINT,CONTRACT_LIST_AMT=BIGINT,CONTRACT_NET_AMT=BIGINT,USD_CONTRACT_LIST_AMT=BIGINT,USD_CONTRACT_NET_AMT=BIGINT,EARLIEST_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP,SERVICE_LINE_TERMINATED_DATE=TIMESTAMP,CONTRACT_TERMINATED_DATE=TIMESTAMP,USD_CONV_RATE=BIGINT,NET_VALUE=BIGINT,MASTER_AGREEMENT_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP,DISCOUNT_PERCENT=BIGINT,PRORATE_FLAG=STRING,RGP_ID=BIGINT,CREATION_DATE=TIMESTAMP,CREATED_BY=BIGINT,LAST_UPDATE_DATE=TIMESTAMP,LAST_UPDATED_BY=BIGINT,LAST_UPDATED_LOGIN=BIGINT,REQUEST_ID=BIGINT,PROGRAM_UPDATE_DATE=TIMESTAMP,PROGRAM_APPLICATION_ID=BIGINT,PROGRAM_ID=BIGINT,ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY=STRING,ATTRIBUTE1=STRING,ATTRIBUTE2=STRING,ATTRIBUTE3=STRING,ATTRIBUTE4=STRING,ATTRIBUTE5=STRING,ATTRIBUTE6=STRING,ATTRIBUTE7=STRING,ATTRIBUTE8=STRING,ATTRIBUTE9=STRING,ATTRIBUTE10=STRING,ATTRIBUTE11=STRING,ATTRIBUTE12=STRING,ATTRIBUTE13=STRING,ATTRIBUTE14=STRING,ATTRIBUTE15=STRING,ATTRIBUTE16=STRING,ATTRIBUTE17=STRING,ATTRIBUTE18=STRING,ATTRIBUTE19=STRING,ATTRIBUTE20=STRING,ACCOUNT_SSR=STRING,SHELL_CONTRACT_FLAG=STRING,CONTRACT_START_DATE=TIMESTAMP,CONTRACT_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP" | write_to_log


ssh $1 "sqoop import -D mapred.child.java.opts='\-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom' --connect '$2' --username $3 --password $4 --query \"select CONTRACT_ID,CONTRACT_NUMBER,CONTRACT_STS_CODE,CONTRACT_STATUS,SERVICE_LINE_ID,SERVICE_LINE_NAME,SERVICE_LINE_STS_CODE,SERVICE_LINE_STATUS,SERVICE_LINE_NUMBER,HDR_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID,HDR_CUST_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,HDR_PARTY_ID,HDR_CUSTOMER_NAME,LINE_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID,LINE_CUST_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,LINE_PARTY_ID,LINE_CUSTOMER_NAME,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_ID,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_NAME,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_STS,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_ID,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_NUMBER,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_STS,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_SITE_STS,BILL_TO_PARTY_ID,BILL_TO_PARTY_NUMBER,BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_NAME,BILL_TO_PARTY_STS,BILL_TO_PARTY_SITE_ID,BILL_TO_PARTY_SITE_STS,BILL_TO_LOCATION_ID,BILL_TO_COUNTRY,BILL_TO_STATE_PROV,BILL_TO_CITY,BILL_TO_POSTAL_CODE,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_ID,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_DESC,COVERAGE_BEGIN_DATE,COVERAGE_END_DATE,SERVICE_SALES_REP_USR_ID,SERVICE_SALES_REP_USR_NAME,SERVICE_LINE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,BILLTO_CSC_ID,BILLTO_CSC_NAME,BILLTO_GU_ID,BILLTO_GU_NAME,BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_SALES_CHANNEL,CURRENCY_CODE,CONTRACT_LIST_AMT,CONTRACT_NET_AMT,USD_CONTRACT_LIST_AMT,USD_CONTRACT_NET_AMT,ACCOUNT_TEAM,RENEWAL_SSR,RENEWAL_TEAM,SALES_REGION,ADVANCE_CONTRACT_FLAG,EARLIEST_END_DATE,SERVICE_LINE_TERMINATED_DATE,SVC_LINE_TERMINATION_REASON,CONTRACT_TERMINATED_DATE,USD_CONV_RATE,PRICE_TYPE,NET_VALUE,COTERM_DATE,MARKETING_PROGRAM,MASTER_AGREEMENT_END_DATE,DISCOUNT_PERCENT,PRORATE_FLAG,RGP_ID,CREATION_DATE,CREATED_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,LAST_UPDATED_BY,LAST_UPDATED_LOGIN,REQUEST_ID,PROGRAM_UPDATE_DATE,PROGRAM_APPLICATION_ID,PROGRAM_ID,ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY,ATTRIBUTE1,ATTRIBUTE2,ATTRIBUTE3,ATTRIBUTE4,ATTRIBUTE5,ATTRIBUTE6,ATTRIBUTE7,ATTRIBUTE8,ATTRIBUTE9,ATTRIBUTE10,ATTRIBUTE11,ATTRIBUTE12,ATTRIBUTE13,ATTRIBUTE14,ATTRIBUTE15,ATTRIBUTE16,ATTRIBUTE17,ATTRIBUTE18,ATTRIBUTE19,ATTRIBUTE20,ACCOUNT_SSR,SHELL_CONTRACT_FLAG,CONTRACT_START_DATE,CONTRACT_END_DATE from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE where \\\$CONDITIONS \" --split-by CONTRACT_NUMBER -m 4 --null-string '\\\\N' --null-non-string '\\\\N' --hive-delims-replacement '<EOL>' --boundary-query 'select (select min(CONTRACT_NUMBER) from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE) as minid ,(select max(CONTRACT_NUMBER) from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE) as maxid from dual' --target-dir $5/XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-table $6.XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE --map-column-hive CONTRACT_ID=BIGINT,SERVICE_LINE_ID=BIGINT,HDR_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID=BIGINT,HDR_PARTY_ID=BIGINT,LINE_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID=BIGINT,LINE_PARTY_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_PARTY_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_PARTY_SITE_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_LOCATION_ID=BIGINT,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_ID=BIGINT,COVERAGE_BEGIN_DATE=TIMESTAMP,COVERAGE_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP,SERVICE_LINE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=BIGINT,BILLTO_CSC_ID=BIGINT,BILLTO_GU_ID=BIGINT,CONTRACT_LIST_AMT=BIGINT,CONTRACT_NET_AMT=BIGINT,USD_CONTRACT_LIST_AMT=BIGINT,USD_CONTRACT_NET_AMT=BIGINT,EARLIEST_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP,SERVICE_LINE_TERMINATED_DATE=TIMESTAMP,CONTRACT_TERMINATED_DATE=TIMESTAMP,USD_CONV_RATE=BIGINT,NET_VALUE=BIGINT,MASTER_AGREEMENT_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP,DISCOUNT_PERCENT=BIGINT,PRORATE_FLAG=STRING,RGP_ID=BIGINT,CREATION_DATE=TIMESTAMP,CREATED_BY=BIGINT,LAST_UPDATE_DATE=TIMESTAMP,LAST_UPDATED_BY=BIGINT,LAST_UPDATED_LOGIN=BIGINT,REQUEST_ID=BIGINT,PROGRAM_UPDATE_DATE=TIMESTAMP,PROGRAM_APPLICATION_ID=BIGINT,PROGRAM_ID=BIGINT,ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY=STRING,ATTRIBUTE1=STRING,ATTRIBUTE2=STRING,ATTRIBUTE3=STRING,ATTRIBUTE4=STRING,ATTRIBUTE5=STRING,ATTRIBUTE6=STRING,ATTRIBUTE7=STRING,ATTRIBUTE8=STRING,ATTRIBUTE9=STRING,ATTRIBUTE10=STRING,ATTRIBUTE11=STRING,ATTRIBUTE12=STRING,ATTRIBUTE13=STRING,ATTRIBUTE14=STRING,ATTRIBUTE15=STRING,ATTRIBUTE16=STRING,ATTRIBUTE17=STRING,ATTRIBUTE18=STRING,ATTRIBUTE19=STRING,ATTRIBUTE20=STRING,ACCOUNT_SSR=STRING,SHELL_CONTRACT_FLAG=STRING,CONTRACT_START_DATE=TIMESTAMP,CONTRACT_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP" | write_to_log
```

Comment: What happens, if you don't use `write_to_log`, but simply redirect the standard output of the ssh command to the logfile?

Comment: This does not answer my question. Please try to help me with the issue. Any person who writes a shell script knows that each and every commands output can be redirected to the log file.

Comment: That's exactly the point: Did you verify that redirecting stdout to a file really yields you *more* lines that redirecting to your shell function? Since I see no obvious error in the shell function, this would be the next logical verification step I would do in this case.

Comment: The first time, when `-f "$dir/$log_file_name"` not exists, you touch that file without logging. What is the output of ssh when you don't redirect to write_to_log()?

Comment: I am getting the first 2 to 3 lines of the logs apart from that i am not seeing any other logs.2016-02-08 10:54:36 : Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
2016-02-08 10:54:36 : Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
2016-02-08 10:54:36 : Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
2016-02-08 10:54:36 : Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.